# Gradle build failing after importing Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I started working at a company recently, so I have never used Gradle before -- everything was already set up for the most part. I introduced Junit tests and now I get this and like 50 others.

```
error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Assert;
```

This is the build.gradle in the common folder that I introduced the Junit tests.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

This is settings.gradle in the overall module.

```
include ':app', ':displaydatasvc', ':signalbus', ':common', ':videosvc', ':joinsvc'
```

Comment: Does your company have a maven-repository? Otherwise you could use:
`repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}` before your dependencies. Basically gradle knows that you want this file, but can't find it and also can't download it currently. Maven solves this issue

Comment: It was my understanding that if you're using gradle then you're not using maven. I thought it was an either or, not a both, so to my understanding no, they aren't using maven. would using mavenCentral() still work? Obviously I've googled and read up on Gradle, but I'm far from really grasping how it works, because I never had to do anything with it.

Comment: If you download the Gradle distro, you'll find a PDF of the User Guide, which you should read top to bottom. Gradle uses the "best parts" of both Maven and Ant, it can get its artifacts from a Maven repo perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoshSuttenberg yes `repositories { mavenCentral() }` before your dependencies should work.